Behavior of braces in macros
I am learning about macros to define commands with a variable number of arguments (following this). I saw a behavior that, to me, looks unexpected. If the \newcommand has a brace containing the expression, the macro does not behave as it should. Here is the code and three examples, one with the expected behavior, another one with a brace inside, and another one (my real use case), where I use \marginpar.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{.}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextarg}[1]{ and #1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{.}}

\newcommand{\shoppinglist}[1]{%
    Shopping list: #1\checknextarg}
\newcommand{\shoppinglistbrace}[1]{%
    {Shopping list: #1\checknextarg}}
\newcommand{\shoppinglistmargin}[1]{%
    \marginpar{\par\noindent{\rule{\marginparwidth}{0.4pt}} Shopping list #1\checknextarg}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\shoppinglist{T1}{T2}\par
\shoppinglistbrace{T1}{T2}\par
\shoppinglistmargin{T1}{T2}
\end{document}



Why do you think that \checknextarg}} should work?  Note that this kind of argument parsing is generally a very bad idea. It only works in certain cases.

@daleif I don't think I understand. \checknextarg works first, then there are two closing braces because there are two opening braces (expression + one inside). My final use case will be to put an item list in a margin note, and the length of this list is variable. How else could I achieve that?

I do not understand what yuo are trying to do here. You will never get any data to go inside \marginpar this way. \checknextarg is never getting to see what comes after. The only reason the linked method works is because the situation is very simple, what toy are doing here is not simple.

Leaving \marginpar aside, which I get is more complicated. Why doesn't the second example work? Why does enclosing the expression in another set of {} break the logic of the macro?

It is inside a brace group, so \checknextarg it cannot see what is coming after it. My mental image is that is cannot see outside the { ...} pair. Note you have two {...} paris here. One is a part of the definition, the other is a brace group, lexical grouping if you will.

you should use a comma separated list, don't break latex syntax conventions looking for optional mandatory arguments.  \shoppinglistmargin{T1, T2, T3} is easier to type and does not break latex syntax

First off: commands with a variable number of arguments are evil.
Now an obvious problem: in \shoppinglistbrace and \shoppinglistmargin you have \checknextarg in the wrong place, because all it does is seeing the } that follows.
Leaving aside the last command, which needs a different treatment:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{.}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextarg}[1]{ and #1\checknextarg}

\newcommand{\shoppinglist}[1]{%
    Shopping list: #1\checknextarg}
\newcommand{\shoppinglistbrace}[1]{%
    {Shopping list: #1}\checknextarg}
%\newcommand{\shoppinglistmargin}[1]{%
%    \marginpar{\rule{\marginparwidth}{0.4pt} Shopping list #1}%
%    \checknextarg}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\shoppinglist{T1}{T2}

\shoppinglistbrace{T1}{T2}

%\shoppinglistmargin{T1}{T2}

\end{document}


What about the last one? You need to first collect the arguments and then pass them to \marginpar.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checknextarg}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextarg}{.}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextarg}[1]{ and #1\checknextarg}

\newcommand{\checknextargmp}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\addnextarg\finishmp}

\newcommand{\shoppinglist}[1]{%
    Shopping list: #1\checknextarg}

\newcommand{\shoppinglistmargin}{%
   \def\shopping@list{\rule{\marginparwidth}{0.4pt} Shopping list }% initialize
   \checknextargmp}
\newcommand{\addnextarg}[1]{%
   \expandafter\def\expandafter\shopping@list\expandafter{\shopping@list and #1 }%
   \checknextargmp}
\newcommand{\finishmp}{
   \marginpar{\raggedright\shopping@list.}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\shoppinglist{T1}{T2}

\shoppinglistmargin{T1}{T2}

\end{document}


Of course there's a much better strategy.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\shoppinglist}{m}
 {
  \axll_shoppinglist:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\shoppinglistmargin}{m}
 {
  \marginpar
   {
    \raggedright
    \rule{\marginparwidth}{0.4pt}~
    \axll_shoppinglist:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \axll_shoppinglist:n
 {
  Shopping~list:~\clist_use:nnnn { #1 } { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\shoppinglist{T1}

\shoppinglist{T1,T2}

\shoppinglist{T1,T2,T3}

\shoppinglistmargin{T1}

\shoppinglistmargin{T1,T2}

\shoppinglistmargin{T1,T2,T3}

\end{document}


